# Need Help for FMDatabase File

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite, uitableview

I am using FMDatabase in my project I need to check the data in the table. Is there any tool or anything else that will help me see the db entries which is on real device ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say debug the database?

Comment: @rptwsthi basically what I mean is to check the data in my db file on real device

Comment: @user1201239 you are asking for a tool which is used to view the database?Is it Correct? In Simulator you can easily check by using the tool `SqliteManager`

Comment: @ShangariC exactly thats what I meant

Comment: @user1201239,you just download `SqliteManager` from http://sqlitemanager.en.softonic.com/mac in your mac and in the code you can able to get the db store path.you can able to open that path in sqliteManager and you can view your db

Comment: @ShangariC : Thanks Bro ...will just do that n if any issues in setting up will get back to u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check data from of your applications sqlite file check it on simulator version is easy. Where you initialise database, print `documentDirectory` path in your application:

```
// Get Document Directory path of the device.
- (NSString*) documentsDirectory{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Navigate to that path in Explorer by cmd+G and pasting the path in text box. You'll see one `.sqlite` file in that folder. Open it with any sqlite explorer, I use [Mozilla AdOn](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) or [SQliteManager](http://www.sqlabs.com/store.php).

But if you wanna check db from your device:

- Open device manager Xcode
- Select your device
- Click on installed app installed app in right pan
- Select your app
- Download it (see attached image)
- And then explore the package to find sqlite file in it.

[image: Image showing how to download export app from device]